# Display Data as GridView instead of ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've successfully displayed my Firestore Data as a `ListView()` unfortunately I can't get it to display as a `GridView()`

I've tried many different methods but can't seem to find the right fit - I'd like a two columns `GridView`

*Here is my ListView code :*

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['num']),
              subtitle: Text(data['num']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was easier than I thought :

I just had to change `ListView` to `GridView.count` for it to display as a GridView & set `crossAxisCount: 2` for two columns

```
class UserGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserGridState createState() => _UserGridState();
}

class _UserGridState extends State<UserGrid> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User Data').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _usersStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Text("Loading");
          }

          return GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            children: [
              ...snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data['num']),
                  subtitle: Text(data['num']),
                );
              }).toList(),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Hello")),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SliverGrid must also be a part of CustomScrollView

```
class SliverGridWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverGrid(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              ///no.of items in the horizontal axis
              crossAxisCount: 4,
            ),
            ///Lazy building of list
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                /// To convert this infinite list to a list with "n" no of items,
                /// uncomment the following line:
                /// if (index > n) return null;
                return listItem(Utils.getRandomColor(), "Sliver Grid item:\n$index");
              },
              /// Set childCount to limit no.of items
              /// childCount: 100,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```